# Newlines at the end "$( .... )" get removed in shell scripts. Why?

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, ksh

Can someone explain why the output of these two commands is different?

```
$ echo "NewLine1\nNewLine2\n"
NewLine1
NewLine2
                         <-- Note 2nd newline here
$ echo "$(echo "NewLine1\nNewLine2\n")"
NewLine1
NewLine2
$                        <-- No second newline
```

Is there any good way that I can keep the new lines at the end of the output in "$( .... )" ? I've thought about just adding a dummy letter and removing it, but I'd quite like to understand why those new lines are going away.

Comment: Its the nature of echo to consume white space. I don't have time to test right now, but your dbl-quotes on your problem test, are probably NOT doing what you think. Maybe `echo "$(echo \"NewLine1\nNewLine2\n\")"` will work. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, but you do not need to escape double quotes within the brackets of a "$(....)" statement. It is treated as a new command. It is one of the advantages of using $(...) over ticks ``. The above problem can be reproduced by using ticks too.

Comment: It's documented behaviour: (http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution) -- "... standard output of the command, with any trailing newlines deleted". To get around it, you may have to redirect output to a temp file, and then work with that file.

Comment: That's a good explanation. It's a bit frustrating as I have a script where the new lines at the end of a "$( ... )" statement are important to me. Like I say above, I may append a random letter and then later strip it off.

Comment: @glennjackman: You should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because [that's what POSIX specifies](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_03) and has always been like that in Bourne shells:

> 2.6.3 Command Substitution
>
> Command substitution allows the output of a command to be substituted
>   in place of the command name itself. Command substitution shall occur
>   when the command is enclosed as follows:
>
> $(command)
>
> or (backquoted version):
>
> `command`
>
> The shell shall expand the command substitution by executing command
>   in a subshell environment (see Shell Execution Environment) and
>   replacing the command substitution (the text of command plus the
>   enclosing "$()" or backquotes) with the standard output of the
>   command, removing sequences of one or more <newline> characters at the
>   end of the substitution. Embedded <newline> characters before the end
>   of the output shall not be removed; however, they may be treated as
>   field delimiters and eliminated during field splitting, depending on
>   the value of IFS and quoting that is in effect. If the output contains
>   any null bytes, the behavior is unspecified.

One way to keep the final newline(s) would be

```
VAR="$(command; echo x)"   # Append x to keep newline(s).
VAR=${VAR%x}               # Chop x.
```

Vis.:

```
$ x="$(whoami; echo x)" ; printf '<%s>\n' "$x" "${x%x}"
<user
x>
<user
>
```

But why remove trailing newlines? Because more often than not you want it that way. I'm also programming in perl and I can't count the number of times where I read a line or variable and then need to chop the newline:

```
while (defined ($string = <>)) {
    chop $string;
    frobnitz($string);
}
```

Comment: `VAR="$(command)x"` doesn't keep the final newlines since it's command substitution that strips them.

Comment: @sch Oops, fixed. Thanks for the heads-up.

Answer (score 1):

command substitution removes **every** trailing newline.

It makes sense to remove one. For instance:

```
basename foo/bar
```

outputs `bar\n`. In:

```
var=$(basename foo/bar)
```

you want `$var` to contain `bar`, not `bar\n`.

However in

```
var=$(basename $'foo/bar\n')
```

You would like `$var` to contain `bar\n` (after all, newline is as valid a character as any in a file name on Unix). But all shells remove **every** trailing newline character. That misfeature was in the original Bourne shell and even `rc` which has fixed most of Bourne's flaws has not fixed that one. (though `rc` has the ``` ``(){cmd} ``` syntax to not strip any newline character).

In POSIX shells, to work around the issue, you can do:

```
var=$(basename -- "$file"; echo .)
var=${var%??}
```

Though you're then losing the exit status of `basename`. Which you can fix with:

```
var=$(basename -- "$file" && echo .) && var=${var%??}
```

`${var%??}` is to remove the last two characters. The first one is the `.` that we added above, the second is the *one* newline character added by `basename`, we're not removing any more as command substitution would do as the other newline characters, if any, would be part of the filename we want to get the base of, so we do want them.

In the Bourne shell which doesn't have the `${var%x}` operator, you had to go a long and convoluted way to work around it.

Answer (score 1):

If the newlines were not removed, then constructs like:

```
x="$(pwd)/filename"
```

would not work usefully, but the people who wrote Unix preferred useful behaviour.

Once, briefly, a very long time ago (like 1983, maybe 1984), I suffered from a shell update on a particular variant of Unix that didn't remove the trailing newline.  It broke scripts all over the place.  It was fixed very quickly.